# CSS Background Image not showing on GitHub pages?

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I uploaded this site on a new repository I've been working on and the only issue left I have with it is that the background that I implemented in the .description class of my code will not show up when I uploaded it online. It looks fine locally, but is a big grey box behind my large text when I put it on Pages.

Here is the code snippet where I inserted the URL.

```css
.description
{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(/images/description-background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px .5px 0px;
}
```

And here is the link to the page: https://github.uconn.edu/pages/ssw19002/devduos/.

Comment: The console says error 404. Under the given URL your image can't be found. Check your URL and check is there a photo at the end of it.

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is! I have the CSS and Images into two separate folders in my main project's folder. So I will probably have to copy the relative path of the image in reference to the css folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this as the folder path `../images/description-background.jpg`

.. is to go back in the file path for instance if I needed a img that was in my images folder and I was editing my CSS in my css folder I would have to do ../images/img.png

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick that u can use style atribute in html file with background-image and url ('./images/description-background.jpg'). this should be work 100% just leave Github a while to load the image.